# Cyclical information request in MySQL stored proc or query

Tags: mysql, sql

In my script, I need to receive information from database (with httpd log file), by everyday traffic consumption.

So, if was 30 day in month I do it with following code, 30 times in cycle:

```
$sql = "SELECT round(sum(bytes)/1048576) FROM logdata WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN '2012-" .$aMonth . "-" . $aDay ." 00:00:00' AND '2012-" .$aMonth . "-" . $aDay ." 23:59:59' AND status=200";
```

It works rather slow.

I think, it possible to receive all results for all days in one resultset, with stored proc, or query.

Can anybody help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT day,ROUND(total/1048576)
FROM (
    SELECT DATE(time_stamp) day,sum(bytes) total
    FROM logdata
    WHERE status=200
    GROUP BY 1
) t;
```

Comment: +1, but you don't need to subselect. `round(sum(bytes)/1048576)` in the same select, like in the OP's example, would work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you have to do is to find out where the slowness derives from. Basically there are usually two possibilities:

1. Your `SELECT`-statement is "slow",
2. Your script is slow.

If your script is slow, please post more of that script in order to give people something to analyze.

If your `SELECT`-statement is "slow", start with a look into the database and table definition first. Are the fields `time_stamp` and `status` indexed? An index on those two fields will almost certainly improve the statements performance significantly.

If it is slow because you're calling the statement 30 times with different values, maybe try receiving your data within just one statement, it then might look something like this:

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(time_stamp, "%y-%m") AS "_month",
        DATE_FORMAT(ROUND(SUM(bytes)/1048576) 
FROM    logdata 
WHERE   time_stamp BETWEEN '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-01-31 23:59:59' 
        AND status=200
GROUP BY _month;
```